# Enviando variável do PHP externo para o Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso receber uma mensagem enviada do PHP, e preciso recebe-la na tela, para avisar se o login está correto ou não. Porém não quero utilizar ajax.

O código que estou recebendo no script interno a index:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){         
        if ($_SESSION['VALIDACAO'] == 01){
            var Texto = "Login inválido"
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = Texto;
        }else{
            var Texto = "Úsuario bloqueado, contacte o administrador do sistema."
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = Texto;
        };
    });
</script>
```

Meu php:

```
<?php


include ("../includes/conexao.php");

$email = ($_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL']);
$senha = ($_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT COD_IDENT_USUAR, TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, FLG_STATU_USUAR FROM tbl_USUARIOS WHERE TXT_ENDER_EMAIL = '".$email."' AND TXT_SENHA_USUAR = '".$senha."'";
$qr = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($qr) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    $_SESSION['VALIDACAO'] = 01;
    header("Location: ../index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);


    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['COD_IDENT_USUAR'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioEmail'] = $resultado['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioFlag'] = $resultado['FLG_STATU_USUAR'];

    if($resultado['FLG_STATU_USUAR'] == 'A'){
    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: ../paginas/principal.php"); exit;
    }else{
        session_destroy(); // Destrói a sessão limpando todos os valores salvos
        $_SESSION['VALIDACAO'] = 02;
        header("Location: ../index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante

    }
}
?>
```

O novo modelo está funcionando da seguinte maneira.
index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'scripts/help.php'; 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>JR Tela de login</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="js/principal01.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" id="from" name="form" method="POST" action="scripts/validacao.php">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">JR Comunicações</h2>

            <div id="msg"><?php get_msg('msg_login');?></div>

            <input type="text" name="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" name="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Senha">
            <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

O arquivo help.php:

```
<?php
// Função para setar a mensagem
function set_msg($id, $msg, $tipo)
{
    session_start();
    if (isset($id)) {
       $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
       switch ($tipo) {

        case 'error':
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert-danger">' . $msg . '</div>';
            break;

        case 'alert':
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert-alert">' . $msg . '</div>';
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Esta função vai exibir sua mensagem onde você quiser
function get_msg($id)
{
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) { echo $_SESSION['msg']; }
    if (isset($id)) {
        if ($id == $_SESSION['id']) {
            echo $_SESSION['msg']; 
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

?>
```

e o validação.php:

```
<?php
include ("../includes/conexao.php");
include("help.php");

$email = ($_POST['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL']);
$senha = ($_POST['TXT_SENHA_USUAR']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT COD_IDENT_USUAR, TXT_NOMEX_USUAR, TXT_ENDER_EMAIL, FLG_STATU_USUAR FROM tbl_USUARIOS WHERE TXT_ENDER_EMAIL = '".$email."' AND TXT_SENHA_USUAR = '".$senha."'";
$qr = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($qr) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    set_msg('msg_login', 'Login ou senha inválidos', 'error');
    header("Location: ../index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);


    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['COD_IDENT_USUAR'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['TXT_NOMEX_USUAR'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioEmail'] = $resultado['TXT_ENDER_EMAIL'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioFlag'] = $resultado['FLG_STATU_USUAR'];

    if($resultado['FLG_STATU_USUAR'] == 'A'){
    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: ../paginas/principal.php"); exit;
    }else{
        session_destroy(); // Destrói a sessão limpando todos os valores salvos
        set_msg('msg_login', 'Usuario bloqueado', 'error');
        header("Location: ../index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: A função get_msg() ta errada amigo:
Faz assim:
function get_msg($id)
{
    session_start();
    
    if (isset($id) && $id == $_SESSION['id']) {
           if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) { echo $_SESSION['msg']; 
    }
    return FALSE;
}

Comment: Ainda está dando erro, aqui o if (isset($id) && $id == $_SESSION['id']) {

Comment: no início da função get_msg() logo após o session_start();
Coloca este código:

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
die;
e coloca aqui o que aparecer ai.

Comment: Array
(
    [UsuarioID] => 1
    [UsuarioNome] => Renan Moraes
    [UsuarioEmail] => renan@hotmail.com
    [UsuarioFlag] => A
)

Comment: Você já tem uma sessão criada da um session_destroy(); ai pra testar.

Comment: nao funcionou, da erro neste comando destroy.

Comment: Qual método mais correto para resolver isto, terei que dar uma saída 13:50 eu volto, peço que me ajude, é para um trabalho para faculdade que terei que entregar sábado.

Comment: Voltei conseguiu identificar algo ?

Comment: @KayoBruno mesmo assim não está funcionando seu codigo. Da erro na linha if (isset($id) && $id == $_SESSION['id']) {

Comment: Debate no meta relevante para esta pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3918/132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você não precisa usar javascript ou jquery, como você não quer usar Ajax você pode utilizar apenas o PHP mesmo. Crie um arquivo "helper" que irá conter funções auxiliares e faça as seguintes funções:

```
// Função para setar a mensagem
public function set_msg($id, $msg, $tipo)
{
    if (isset($id)) {
       $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
       switch ($tipo) {

        case 'error':
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert-danger">' . $msg . '</div>';
            break;

        case 'alert':
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert-alert">' . $msg . '</div>';
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Esta função vai exibir sua mensagem onde você quiser
public function get_msg($id)
{
    if (isset($id)) {
        if ($id == $_SESSION['id']) {
            echo $_SESSION['msg']; 
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Na sua rotina de login, dependendo do resultado você chama a função set_msg() passando seus parâmetros e na sua página de login você coloca a função get_msg() onde você quer que a mensagem apareça.

Exemplo de uso das funções:

```
set_msg('msg_login', 'Login ou senha inválidos', 'error');
get_msg('msg_login');
```

Comment: Porem como vou saber se deu erro ou não, porque no php, nao sei se voce viu, eu faço um echo 01 caso o login for invalido, e 02 caso o usuario for bloqueado.

Comment: Alem eu queria seta um texto a div.msg

Comment: Na sua rotina de login, em vez de você colocar "$_SESSION['VALIDACAO'] = 01;" você chama a função set_msg() e dentro da div que você quiser você chama a função get_msg()

Comment: outra coisa, quando o documento roda pela primeira vez ele da erro, pois não encontra nada dentro de mensagem, como resolver ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_msg() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/index.php on line 17 ///  //// ta dando este erro

Comment: Coloca um if pra verificar se $_SESSION['msg'] é diferente de vazio dentro da função get_msg();

Comment: assim o :  if (!($_SESSION['msg']) == "") {  ???

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
}

Comment: Agora ta dando seguinte erro, porque tenho que colocar um include no arquivo help na pagina inicial, porem ele ta dando erro na primeira função. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/scripts/help.php on line 3

Comment: o que tem na linha 3?

Comment: public function set_msg($id, $msg, $tipo)

Comment: retira o public das duas funções!

Comment: Agora o erro ta aqui o: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/scripts/help.php on line 25

Comment: if ($id == $_SESSION['id']) { a linha é esta

Comment: da um session_start(); no inicio das duas funções.

Comment: da o erro ainda.

Comment: Atualizei, como está todas as paginas para você visualizar melhor, para poder me ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você não está colocando a *tag* *`php`* na verificação que você está fazendo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){         
        <?php if ($_SESSION['VALIDACAO'] == 01){?>
            var Texto = "Login inválido"
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = Texto;
        <?php }else{?>
            var Texto = "Úsuario bloqueado, contacte o administrador do sistema."
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = Texto;
        <?php };?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Da este erro, e no log do PHP fala que a variavel nao foi definida

Comment: Qual variável não foi definida?

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma mais simples: realize as verificações direto no php e passe o resultado para o js.

```
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['VALIDACAO'] == 01) {
        $texto = "Login inválido";
    } else {
        $texto = "Úsuario bloqueado, contacte o administrador do sistema.";
    }
?>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {         
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "<?php echo $texto ?>";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/index.php on line 4

Comment: Ta acontecendo o seguinte, ele está lendo o documento, e está dando erro pois não tem nada dentro da variável.

Comment: Qual é a linha 4 no seu arquivo `index.php`?